# Haproxy: how to switch back to primary server

Tags: haproxy

i am using haproxy for sometime and it perfectly works fine. But i had one query from my team. what if primary server comes back online.. the request should got to primary server instead of backend servers. Below are my configuration details. Please help me the resolve the issue.

basically in below configuration my request are going to primary server that is Server1 and Server2 in a roundrobin way. If both the primary server goes down it switches to backup server that is Server3 and Server4. Now if both the Primary server becomes live i want all the request should go to the primary server and not to backup server. How can i do this configuration? help will be highly appreciated.

```
frontend Local_Server
bind ssbbct1076:39250
mode http
default_backend Web_Server

backend Web_Server
balance roundrobin
option httplog
option log-health-checks
option allbackups
server Server1 s2bbct01:39249 check
server Server2 s2bbct02:39249 check
server Server3 c1bbct01:39249 check backup
server Server4 c1bbct02:39249 check backup
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [option redispatch](http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/2.4/configuration.html#4.2-option%20redispatch) to redispatch a request to the active servers